# find *.tar then extract and delete the files

Tags: linux, bash, find, tar, xargs

I'm trying to find a tar file, extract the files then remove all the extracted files - I'm able to perform the find and extraction or find the file and remove it but I'm not able to string all three together.

Here is my best attempt below. It runs without error but doesn't delete the extracted files so I'm stuck on how to remove the files I've extracted to the current directory.

```
find  ~ -name '*.tar' | xargs tar -xf && rm -f
```

I tried extracting the tar to another directory then removing the directory but couldn't get it to work while using xargs. I've tried searching quite a few different areas but couldn't find anything so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you want to remove the extracted files or the tarballs?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I ended up running: find -name 'file.tar' | xargs tar -xvf | xargs rm -f && rm 'file.tar' -f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&&` ends the pipeline, it's not part of the `xargs` command.

You can just run the commands using the `-exec` option to `find`:

```
find ~ -name '*.tar' -exec tar -xf {} \; -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: A nice feature of this approach is that the second `exec` only runs if the first `exec` succeeded.  Thus, it is logically like having `&&` between the commands.

Answer (score 2):

To run two or multiple commands with xargs:

```
find  ~ -name '*.tar' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'tar -xf {} && rm -f {}'
```

Only after successfully unpacking the tar file is deleted.